# Slowly auto scroll content to right inside the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the best way to auto scrolling the content inside the element.

CSS

```
.wrapper{
 overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="Wrapper">
<table>
...
</table>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.Wrapper').scrollLeft($(this).height());
```

I found the code above works very well but without slowly movement.
Need a bit explanation and make it an slowly animate.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method animate and set the value to slow, example:

```js
$('button').on('click', event => {
  $('#mycontent').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#mycontent').scrollTop() + (($('#mycontent').scrollTop() >= 229) ? (-229) : (100))
  }, 'slow')
})
```

```css
#mycontent {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Scroll</button>
<div id="mycontent">
  JavaScript (/ˈdʒɑːvəˌskrɪpt/),[6] often abbreviated as JS, is a programming language that conforms to the ECMAScript specification.[7] JavaScript is high-level, often just-in-time compiled, and multi-paradigm. It has curly-bracket syntax, dynamic typing, prototype-based object-orientation, and first-class functions.

Alongside HTML and CSS, JavaScript is one of the core technologies of the World Wide Web.[8] JavaScript enables interactive web pages and is an essential part of web applications. The vast majority of websites use it for client-side page behavior,[9] and all major web browsers have a dedicated JavaScript engine to execute it.

As a multi-paradigm language, JavaScript supports event-driven, functional, and imperative programming styles. It has application programming interfaces (APIs) for working with text, dates, regular expressions, standard data structures, and the Document Object Model (DOM). However, the language itself does not include any input/output (I/O), such as networking, storage, or graphics facilities, as the host environment (usually a web browser) provides those APIs.

JavaScript engines were originally used only in web browsers, but they are now embedded in some servers, usually via Node.js. They are also embedded in a variety of applications created with frameworks such as Electron and Cordova.
</div>
```

**Note:** In my example I used scrollTop, for your just change to scrollLeft

Comment: If you are unable to do

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question - Checkout [Full Implementation](https://codepen.io/sumitpal29/pen/MWaRzGM) here

If you want to scroll automatic in a continuous fashion (horizontally / vertically) you have to implement these steps -

Parent Element - with scroll property [i.e. overflow-x]
Child Element - larger than parent

Create a animation function with which we can scroll the child element with in a given time - which require three params 
 - time to complete the animation
 - animation behaviour [linear/ Bounce etc] 
 - a function which takes progress of the animation as param and so some changes on the DOM

```
const content = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
const innerContent = document.getElementsByClassName("inner-content")[0];
const innerContentWidth = innerContent.getBoundingClientRect().width;
const contentWidth = content.getBoundingClientRect().width;

function animate({ timing, draw, duration }) {
  let start = performance.now();

  requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
// timeFraction goes from 0 to 1

let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

// calculate the current animation state
let progress = timing(timeFraction);

draw(progress); // draw it

if (timeFraction < 1) {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
  });
}

animate({
  duration: 40000, // specify the time of scrolling in ms
  timing(timeFraction) {
    return timeFraction;
  },
  draw(progress) {
    const percent = progress * 100;
    content.scrollTo(percent * ((innerContentWidth - contentWidth) / 100), 0);
    console.log(percent);

    // couple of other ways you can implement the same using other css props
    // innerContent.style.transform = `translateX(-${percent * 20}px)`;
    // innerContent.style.left = `-${percent * ((innerContentWidth - contentWidth) / 100)}px`
  }
});
```

Read more about

- [window scroll methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)
- [JavaScript Animation and requestAnimationFrame](https://javascript.info/js-animation)

Comment: I definitely learn a lot more from your answer as I have spent too much time on jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, Dave,  it is always a good practice to use plain js (when you have time) and explore & learn new things.